# Can a coin be biased?

Tags: interpretation, bias

If I have a coin that is not necessarily expected to turn up heads half of the time, then is it correct to call the coin biased?  Or does *bias* in statistics only mean the bias of an estimator in which case it would be inappropriate to describe the coin itself as biased?

This question does not mean to be about issues like [this](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/diceRev2.pdf), so maybe a different example would have been better.

Comment: A coin that turns up Heads with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ is often called a fair coin, so I suppose you could call your coin an _unfair_ coin (or a coin that is _not fair_ if you don't want to sound pejorative) if you wish to reserve the adjective _biased_ for estimators only.

Comment: Interesting fact: it's *really* hard to make an unfair coin. We did an experiment for first year stats, were we made a bunch - one cupped, one bent (about 20°), one with lots of holes drilled in one side (ie. reduced weight). After 200 flips, none of them came up with a p<0.05, although one was close (I think the bent one). You're better off learning to flip accurately, if you want to win at coins, and even then, you have to flip low, with few rotations, and it's gonna be pretty obvious what you're doing to anyone watching.

Comment: Technically no asymmetric coin (e.g. one that has heads and tails) is likely to be unbiased, as this requires the probability of a head being *exactly* 0.5.  So the test for the un-biasedness of a coin is one where the null hypothesis is known to be false from the outset, and if you toss the coin enough you will always be able to demonstrate that it is biased, no matter how small the "effect size".  But while we can't have an unbiased coin, it is (as naught101 suggests - +1) difficult to make a significantly biased coin, without it having heads on both sides.

Answer (score 4):

From my connotation the coin is the data generating process (DGP) therefore it cannot be biased - but rather be *unfair* as Dilip Sarwate noted correctly. The expected value of the estimator should match the true value of the DGP if it does not we call it biased.

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on the audience.  In everyday language, we would call a coin "biased"; it's only in a strict statistical sense that bias means something else.

It's one of many terms that statisticians use to mean something slightly different from what it means to everyone else.

Comment: So if you were writing a textbook titled _An Introduction to Probability for Scientists and Engineers,_ it would be a biased coin, while if the book were titled _Statistics: An Introductory Course_ it would be an unfair coin? I wonder what terminology the numerous _Probability and Statistics for Scientists and Engineers_ books use.

Comment: +1; @DilipSarwate, a *good* book would have a couple of sentences that would introduce / explain the terminology and differentiate it from similar--but not identical--colloquial uses that might otherwise lead to confusion.  (I don't know how many texts meet my definition of 'good', though.)