# Stories about statistics, machine learning and data mining

Tags: machine-learning, probability, data-mining

I'm looking for interesting stories about statistics, machine learning, etc.
Examples of stories I find interesting are the following:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss developed the least squares method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) in order to predict the occurrence of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceres_(dwarf_planet)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre-Simon_Laplace developed the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_smoothing method while working on the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_problem

The origin of the term confusion matrix.
[What is the origin of the term confusion matrix?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164910/what-is-the-origin-of-the-term-confusion-matrix)

Comment: "Interesting" is in the eye of the beholder.  We aren't set up for such discussions here.  Please visit our [help] for information on what kinds of questions can be addressed.

Comment: I agree, it is subjective. I can remove the interesting from the title.  I think the site is a great place for such discussions, like the one on jokes - http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/statistics-jokes

Comment: See @whuber's comment there: "please don't use the existence of this thread to justify creating new ones that fall outside our guidelines unless you think there is a very good reason to do so!"

Comment: OK, I see. I would be very happy to get answers to this question here. If you think it is suitable, please make it public.

Comment: There's a fun story about the origins of hypothesis testing and the Fisher's exact test: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lady_tasting_tea. The history behind the Monte Carlo method is also interesting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method.